# how can i replace json string?

Tags: iphone

i want to replace particular data's in json string

Answer (score 3):

Parse it, make the changes you need, then serialize it back out.  You didn't say what JSON library you're using, but it should be fairly easy.

Comment: *Please* tell us what library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your problem:

```
[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"replaceme" withString:@"replacement"];
```

But you're probably far better of using a [JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application).